# Create new list of objects for each of the item in another object list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object with

```cs
public class test
 { 
     public object obj1;
     public List<string> items;
 }
```

I have a `List<test>`. For each of the `item`s i want to create a *new object* with properties from `obj1` and an `item`. The `items` list can be `null` or empty. Is there a way to do in *Linq*?

Comment: The answer is yes, probably, maybe, no. You'll need to be more specific, describe why you need `object` type for `obj1` whats in it, and some test data and sample output

Comment: probely what you are looking for is `SelectMany`

Comment: Could you provide an *example*?

Comment: Can you describe, in more detail, the object you want to construct? Right now I'm having trouble imagining what you want. Thanks.

Comment: Which properties from `obj1`?

Answer (score 2):

```
List<test> tests = new List<test>();
var ob1=new test{ obj1 = "obj1" };
var ob2=new test{ obj1 = "obj2" };
var ob3=new test{ obj1 = "obj3" };
var ob4=new test{ obj1 = null };
tests.Add(ob1);
tests.Add(ob2);
tests.Add(ob3);
tests.Add(ob4);

var result = tests.Select(e => new NewType
{
     name = e.obj1 != null ? e.obj1.ToString() : null
});

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.name);
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Say Test.Obj1 has two properties you want to include in each new item, 'Name' & 'ID', along with an item from the list - try a query like this.

Will generate a list of new (anonymous) objects with (for example) the first element of each Test.Obj1.List

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> results = tests
    .Select(o => new { Name = o.obj1.Name, 
                       ID = o.obj1.Id, 
                       Item = o.items.First() ?? null} )
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(results.ElementAt(0));
Console.WriteLine(results.ElementAt(1));
Console.WriteLine(results.ElementAt(2));

//  { Name = Foo, ID = 1, Item = a }
//  { Name = Bar, ID = 2, Item = d }
//  { Name = Goo, ID = 3, Item = g }


// Example types below...
public class Obj1
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public Obj1(string name, int id)
    {
        Name = name;
        Id = id;
    }
}

// Create some instances
Obj1 objA = new MyObject("Foo", 1);
Obj1 objB = new MyObject("Bar", 2);
Obj1 objC = new MyObject("Goo", 3);

// Your test class that contains the custom object, and a list
public class Test
{ 
    public Obj1 obj1;
    public List<string> items;

    public Test(Obj1 myobject, List<string> myItems)
    {
        obj1 = myobject;
        items = myItems;
    }
}

// Make a list of test objects
List<Test> tests = new List<Test>{
    new Test(objA, new List<string>{"a", "b", "c"}),
    new Test(objB, new List<string>{"d", "e", "f"}),
    new Test(objC, new List<string>{"g", "h", "i"})};
```

For new{}, you can replace with a named type T and constructor as needed and update the results list to be

```
IEnumerable<T>
```

Also, you may have a specific criteria for which item in the list you want (or all) so you could add a more interesting query in the constructor rather than .First()

Or to just grab the whole test item adjust the constructor as

```
new { Obj = o.obj1, Items = o.items}
```

Hope this helps - there are some great links in this collection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-a-subquery-on-a-grouping-operation